# Using @@ to mark private code does not prevent conflict between modules

Tags: expl3, dtx

The [doc for expl3](http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/expl3.pdf) says: [image]

In the code below, `pkgA` and `pkgB` both define `\@@_foo:`, and `pkgB` relies on `pkgA`. I would have thought `%<@@=module>` would prevent this error:

> ERROR: LaTeX3 Error: Control sequence `\@@_foo:` already defined.

Why isn't it the case?

**pkgA:**

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
% !TEX program  = pdfLaTeX
%<*internal> 
\iffalse
%</internal> 
%<*internal> 
\fi
\def\nameofplainTeX{plain}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX\else
\expandafter\begingroup
\fi
%</internal> 
%<*install> 
\input docstrip.tex
\keepsilent
\askforoverwritefalse
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.sty}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{package}}
}
%</install> 
%<install> \endbatchfile
%<*internal> 
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.ins}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{install}}
}
\nopreamble\nopostamble
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX
\expandafter\endbatchfile
\else
\expandafter\endgroup
\fi
%</internal> 
%<package> \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2020/02/02]
%<package> \RequirePackage{expl3}
%<package> \ProvidesExplPackage
%<package> {pkgA}                                                                                 % Package name
%<package> {2020/04/17}                                                                           % Release date
%<package> {1.0}                                                                                  % Release version
%<package> {pkgA --- template for dtx}                                                            % Description
% 
%<*driver> 
\documentclass[full]{l3doc}
\usepackage{pkgA}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% \char`[
\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineIndex
\RecordChanges
\begin{document}
\DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver> 
% \fi
% \GetFileInfo{\jobname.sty}
% \begin{documentation}
% \end{documentation}
% \begin{implementation}
%   \iffalse
%<*package>   
%   \fi
%<@@=pkgA>
%    \begin{macrocode}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Nn \@@_foo:{Hello, world!}
\ExplSyntaxOff
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{implementation}
% 
% \iffalse
%</package> 
% \fi
% \Finale
\endinput
```

**pkgB:**

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
% !TEX program  = pdfLaTeX
%<*internal> 
\iffalse
%</internal> 
%<*internal> 
\fi
\def\nameofplainTeX{plain}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX\else
\expandafter\begingroup
\fi
%</internal> 
%<*install> 
\input docstrip.tex
\keepsilent
\askforoverwritefalse
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.sty}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{package}}
}
%</install> 
%<install> \endbatchfile
%<*internal> 
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.ins}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{install}}
}
\nopreamble\nopostamble
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX
\expandafter\endbatchfile
\else
\expandafter\endgroup
\fi
%</internal> 
%<package> \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2020/02/02]
%<package> \RequirePackage{pkgA}
%<package> \ProvidesExplPackage
%<package> {pkgB}                                                                                 % Package name
%<package> {2020/04/17}                                                                           % Release date
%<package> {1.0}                                                                                  % Release version
%<package> {pkgB --- template for dtx}                                                            % Description
% 
%<*driver> 
\documentclass[full]{l3doc}
\usepackage{pkgB}
\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineIndex
\RecordChanges
\begin{document}
\DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver> 
% \fi
% \GetFileInfo{\jobname.sty}
% \begin{documentation}
% \end{documentation}
% \begin{implementation}
%   \iffalse
%<*package>   
%   \fi
%<@@=pkgB>
%    \begin{macrocode}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Nn \@@_foo:{Jello, world!}
\ExplSyntaxOff
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{implementation}
% 
% \iffalse
%</package> 
% \fi
% \Finale
\endinput
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `@@` syntax is a convention for setting up sources to make internal functions/variables both obvious and short. However, TeX itself doesn't 'know' about that, so if you do nothing else, you are actually calling your control sequence `\@@_foo:`. What you need to do is extract your `.dtx` file using `l3docstrip`, rather than 'vanilla' DocStrip. `l3docstrip` will replace `@@` by the `<module>` and the appropriate internal prefix as it extracts code lines. So it would generate `\__pkgA_foo:` and `\__pkgB_foo:` in the `.sty` files here.

Comment: OK, so replace `\input docstrip.tex` by `\input l3docstrip.tex`? Yeah, it worked, thx.

Comment: @Erwann Yes, exactly: basically this ability _is_ the difference between the two versions of DocStrip

Comment: @JosephWright  We could add an explicit sentence to the documentation that one can't use docstrip in the .ins file. (it is implicitly there but the "l3" is easily overlooked

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Sure: I thought the fact it says 'l3docstrip' was enough, but perhaps not

Comment: @JosephWright it wasn't this time :-) but I think it is easy to overlook, especially if you convert an existing setup that already as an .ins file -- it would hurt to add a sentence, I'll do it.